# (ANDROID) REST API sending same data for some time

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, android-volley

I am using NewsData.io api for my news app. The app sends the same data no matter how many time you refresh it for a fixed time. After the fixed time it will send another data for a fixed time and so on.I am using volley library.
Here is my networking class

```
package com.example.news

import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest

class Networking {

    interface NewsFetchListener{
        fun onNewsFetched(newsList:ArrayList<News>)
        fun onError()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val baseUrl =
            "https://newsdata.io/api/1/news?apikey=API_KEY&language=en&country=in&category="


        fun fetchData(category: String, context: Context,listener:NewsFetchListener): ArrayList<News> {
            val newsList = ArrayList<News>()
            Log.d("Networking", "start")
            val url = baseUrl + category
            val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                {
                    val results = it.getJSONArray("results")

                    for (i in 0 until results.length()) {
                        val article = results.getJSONObject(i)

                        val news = News(
                            article.getString("title"),
                            article.getString("description"),
                            article.getString("image_url"),
                            article.getString("pubDate"),
                            article.getString("source_id"),
                            article.getString("link")
                        )
                        newsList.add(news)

                    }
                    listener.onNewsFetched(newsList)
                },{
                    val statusCode = it.networkResponse?.statusCode
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "Error - status code: $statusCode")
                    listener.onError()

                })
            MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest)
            return newsList
        }

    }
}
```

Is it possible to get different data every time we refresh?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the tag for the language you are using

Comment: Can you check with NewsData.io API support team may its because data is changed when updates are available from API side if there are no new updates they are sending old data.

Comment: @Vishal But in other apps if there is no new news they show old but different news, How do i implement that?

Comment: Sorry I don't have much idea about the NewsData.io integration, But it could be a case they are storing data on client side as well and show the same if there is no data coming from api end

Comment: I know this does not answer your question, but have you tried to use something better than JsonObjectRequest like Retrofit? It's way easy to find answers for problems with a very used library like this one and to implement it is very simple :)

Comment: @LeonardodeOliveiraSibela Is retrofit better than volley library?

Comment: @KaranKumar yep. People use retrofit way more than volley. It is cleaner, works with a lot of kotlin features and it's just awesom :)